# Regex - trouble matching the pattern "(cmd: )"

Tags: java, regex

I am having trouble getting my regex to match the pattern `"(cmd: .*)"`.
For example, I want to match `"(cmd: cd $HOME)"`.

Here is my regex : `\(cmd:\s+.*\)`

The problem is, this will also match `"(cmd: char) ()"`. Since there is a `".*"` inside the regex, it will match all `")"` until the last one it sees. How, do I modify the regex so that it will match something like `"(cmd: (asd) )"` but not if `")"` does not have a matching `"("`. So for instance, the regex would not match the very last parenthesis of this string: `"(cmd: asd) )"`.

Comment: What regex flavor are you using?

Comment: Hi @anubhava, I am using which ever flavor Java uses. I have removed the extra escape slashes for readability.

Comment: ok then `\\(cmd:\\s+.*?\\)` should work in Java.

Comment: @Renren29 Which string do you want to match in this `(cmd: (asd) )`?

Comment: Hi Avinash, preferably I would like to match "matching parenthesis" inside "(cmd:)". However, if there is something like this : (cmd: ))" or "(cmd: ) ()", I would not like to match those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give you one Java implementation sample as below:

```
    String str3 = "(cmd: (((char))) (ddt)) ()";
    String regexp = "\\(cmd: "+ nestingPair(5, '(', ')')+ "\\)";
    Pattern pMod = Pattern.compile(regexp);
    Matcher mMod = pMod.matcher(str3);
    while (mMod.find()) {
        System.out.println(mMod.group(0));
    }

public String nestingPair(int level, char b, char e) {
    String ret = "";
    if (level <= 0) { return ret; }

    String common = "(?>[^" + b + e + "]*(?>\\\\" + b + "888_888" + "\\\\" + e + ")*[^" + b + e
            + "]*)*";
    String core = "[^" + b + e + "]*";
    String replace = "(?>[^" + b + e + "]*(?>\\" + b + "888_888" + "\\" + e + ")*[^" + b + e
            + "]*)*";
    for (int i = 0; i < level - 1; i++) {
        // System.out.println(replace);
        replace = replace.replaceFirst("888_888", common);
    }
    // System.out.println(replace);
    ret = replace.replaceAll("888_888", core);

    return ret;
}
```

Then, the output is:

```
(cmd: (((char))) (ddt))
```

One remark: The recursive level could be set according to your actual requirements. (in my sample, I set it to 5, normally, I think is enough. I have tried 500, it's ok. but for 1000 , it'll be StackOverFlow).
Since normally, Java-regex doesn't support the Matching Text with Nested Parentheses or any other Nested characters. (e.g. (), {}, [], <>, etc).
There is one open source project ["jree"](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jree/), which has provided this kind of support. FYI.

Answer (score 1):

I would add another group to capture only thing you need.

```
^\(cmd\:(.*)\)$
```

Comment: How does a group capture help, or even change what's matched?

Comment: @Bohemian from OP comment >preferably I would like to match "matching parenthesis" inside "(cmd:)" 
so it would help to match what he need but would not help with extra parances, which is imposible since java regexp doesnt support recurisve pattern (?R)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to accomplish this with a regex. Brace or parenthesis matching requires a recursive/counting feature that is not available in a regex. You'll need a parser for this.

More details available here: http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2008/10/15/regular-expression-limitations.aspx

Comment: You are mistaken. It can, and has, been [done](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25205604/256196).

Comment: Oh yeah? Tell me why `(cmd: ((something)))` doesn't work on that Regex?

Comment: Who says they need to?

Answer (score 0):

You want a regex that allows brackets in the match, but only if they are paired. Like this regex:

```
\(cmd:\s+([^()]*\([^()]\))*[^()]*\)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/J5stvp8duY)

Comment: Recursive brace matching does not work: `(cmd: (cd (cd something)))` or `(cmd: ((cd)))`

Comment: @matt no, but none of the examples had nested brackets, so that's out of scope for the question.

Comment: Your answer says: `You want a regex that allows brackets in the match, but only if they are paired.` Clearly this involves any amount of nested brackets. Specify your answer

Comment: @mati My regex does exactly what it says it does: Brackets if paired. Not nested. Ie `"for (bar) (baz) foo"`. Paired. However, I can make the regex work for any given depth of nesting, it would just become a bit longer for every extra depth catered for.